# How to transform arrow to Int/String value PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have this sql code and I know i'll have only one result anytime but the query result is an array. How to I get a string or int value ?

```
$MEMBER_ID = $this->db
     ->select ('MEMBER_ID', false)
     ->from($this->table_member)   
     ->where('MEMBER_EMAIL, $this->input->post('InputEmail'))
     ->get()
     ->result();
```

Using CodeIgniter.

Thank you,

Comment: you can't get string instead of array. But you can assign to variable using `list()` function while fetching results itself.

Comment: Yeah, try using `var_export($MEMBER_ID);` that will tell you what are you dealing with everytime, not just for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly that query gets only one result then take field `MEMBER_ID` from the first array element:

```
$MEMBER_ID = $this->db
             ->select ('MEMBER_ID', false)
             ->from($this->table_member)   
             ->where('MEMBER_EMAIL, $this->input->post('InputEmail'))
             ->get()
             ->result()[0]['MEMBER_ID'];
```

Or use simpler query like this:

```
$MEMBER_ID = $this->db->query("Select MEMBER_ID from table_member where id = $id")->row()->MEMBER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all those Query Builder calls for such a simple query. This will work just fine.

```
$id = $this->input->post('InputEmail');

$MEMBER_ID = $this->db
     ->query("Select MEMBER_ID from {$this->table_member} where id = $id")
     ->row()
     ->MEMBER_ID;
```

But if you insist on the hard way

```
$MEMBER_ID = $this->db
     ->select ('MEMBER_ID', false)
     ->from($this->table_member)   
     ->where('MEMBER_EMAIL, $this->input->post('InputEmail'))
     ->get()
     ->row()
     ->MEMBER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have known the query should only return 1 result , than don't use `ressult()`, or `result_array()`

Check this out :
[Generating Query Results](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html).

So on your code u can try this

in `row()` exception :

```
$MEMBER_ID = $this->db
     ->select ('MEMBER_ID', false)
     ->from($this->table_member)   
     ->where('MEMBER_EMAIL, $this->input->post('InputEmail'))
     ->get()
     ->row()->MEMBER_ID;
return $MEMBER_ID;
```

in `row_array()`

```
$MEMBER_ID = $this->db
         ->select ('MEMBER_ID', false)
         ->from($this->table_member)   
         ->where('MEMBER_EMAIL, $this->input->post('InputEmail'))
         ->get()
         ->row_array()['MEMBER_ID'];
return $MEMBER_ID;
```